# In pursuit of the missing tasks: potential discrepancy between reported task numbers and results

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a fairly typical producer-consumer scenario where I have 1 producer thread that executes queries and puts the results to a `BlockingQueue` and approx 7-8 consumers that pick these objects from the `BlockingQueue` and run a rather long lasting analysis on them. Once these analyses are completed, the resultant objects are placed in a `HashMap` with the original objects as keys, *i.e.* `HashMap<AnalyzedObject, AnalysisResult>`

Due to the nature of relationships in the underlying data model, I get a lot of duplicate tasks, which obviously do not need to be reprocessed. My current solution is essentially as follows:

```
public class AnalysisAction implements Runnable{

    private Dataset data;
    private DbManager dbManager;
    private Path path;
    private Set<Integer> identifiedElements;
    private AnalysisResult res;
    private Map<Path, AnalysisResult> analyzedPaths;

    public static final AtomicInteger duplicates = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public AnalysisAction(Path p, Dataset ds, DbManager dbm, Map<Path, AnalysisResult> paths){
        this.data = ds;
        this.path = p;
        this.dbManager = dbm;
        this.analyzedPaths = paths;
        this.res = new AnalysisResult(path);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if(!analyzedPaths.containsKey(path)){
        t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();                
            // 1. Check the coverage of the path 
            this.identifiedElements = getIdentifiedElements();
            if(identifiedElements.size() != 0)
            {                           
                try{
                    // TIME CONSUMING STUFF...

                    analyzedPaths.put(path, res);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    // Exception handling...            
                }
            }

            t_end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            DebugToolbox.submitProcTime(t_end - t0);
        }
        else {
            duplicates.incrementAndGet();
            logger.finer("Duplicate path encountered..." + System.lineSeparator());
        }
    } 
    // PRIVATE METHODS THAT CARRY OUT THE TIME CONSUMING STUFF...   
}
```

Then within the class that controls the multithreading I have the following solution:

```
public class ConcurrencyService {
     private final ThreadPoolExecutor pool;
     private final int poolSize;
     private final int qCapacity = 1 << 7;
     private final long timeout = 3;
     private final Path tainedPath = 
             new Path(Long.MIN_VALUE, "LAST_PATH_IN_QUEUE", "N/A", "N/A"); 

    private BlockingQueue<PathwayImpl> bq;
    private DbManager dbMan;
    private Dataset ds;
    private Map<Path,AnalysisResult> analyzedPaths;
    private volatile boolean started;

    public ConcurrencyService(Dataset data, DbManager db){      
        this.ds = data;
        this.bq = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Path>(qCapacity);
        this.dbMan = db;
        this.analyzedPaths = new ConcurrentHashMap<Path,AnalysisResult>(1<<15);
        this.started = false;

        poolSize = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        pool = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize, new FThreadFactory(-1));         
    }

        public void serve() throws InterruptedException {
            try {
                ds.finalize();
                started = true;

                Thread producerThread = new Thread(new QueryingAction(), "f-query-thread");
                producerThread.start();

                Thread loggerThread = new Thread(new PeriodicLogAction(null), "f-logger-thread");   
                loggerThread.start();

                while((producerThread.getState() != Thread.State.TERMINATED) || !bq.isEmpty()){

                    Path p = bq.poll(timeout, TimeUnit.MINUTES);                        
                    if(p != null){
                        if (p.equals(tainedPath)) break;                                            
                        pool.submit(new AnalysisAction(p, ds, dbMan, analyzedPaths));
                    }else 
                        logger.warning("Timed out while waiting for a path...");

                }

              } catch (Exception ex) {
                  // Exception handling...          
              } finally{

                  pool.shutdown();

                  long  totalTasks = pool.getTaskCount(), 
                        compTasks = pool.getCompletedTaskCount(),
                        tasksRemaining = totalTasks - compTasks,
                        timeout = 10 * tasksRemaining / poolSize;

                  pool.awaitTermination(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                  logger.info(
                          "A total of " + DebugToolbox.getNbrProcTimes() 
                          + " tasks analyzed. Mean process time is: " 
                          + DebugToolbox.getMeanProcTimeAsString() 
                          +  " milliseconds." + System.lineSeparator());
              }

              public boolean isDone(){
                  if(this.started) 
                      return pool.isTerminated();
                  else 
                      return false;
              }
        }

        protected class QueryingAction implements Runnable {

            // Use this to limit the number of paths to be analyzed
//          private final int debugLimiter = 1500;
            private final int debugLimiter = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 

            public void run() {                 
                try {
                    int i = 0;
                    outer: for(String el : ds.getElements()){
                        inner: for(Path path : dbMan.getAllPathsWithElement(el)){
                            if(i++ > debugLimiter)
                                break outer;
                            else
                                bq.put(path);
                        }
                    }

                    logger.info("Total number of queried paths: " + i);

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // Exception handling...
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Exception handling...
                }
                bq.offer(tainedPath);   
            }
        }

        protected class PeriodicLogAction implements Runnable {
            private final PrintStream ps;
            private final long period;
            private final static long DEF_PERIOD = 30000;
            private final String nL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            private volatile boolean loop;
            private int counter = 0;
            private ConcurrencyService cs; 
            private int inQueryQueue, inPoolQueue, 
                            completedTasks, inProccessedSet,duplicates;

            boolean sanityCheck;
            StringBuffer sb;            

            PeriodicLogAction(PrintStream ps, long timePeriod) {    
                this.ps = ps;
                this.period = timePeriod;
                this.loop = true;
                this.cs = ConcurrencyService.this;
            }

            // Alternative constructors

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            public void run() {
                logger.config("PeriodicLogAction started on thread: " + 
                        Thread.currentThread().getName() + 
                        System.lineSeparator());            

                while(loop){
                    // log # of paths created, analyzed and are in queue
                    outputLogInfo();

                    // wait designated time period
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(period);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                    if(cs.isDone()){
                        this.loop = false;
                        outputLogInfo();
                    }
                }
            }

            private void outputLogInfo(){

                synchronized (pool) {
                    Queue   queryQueue = cs.bq,
                            poolQueue = cs.pool.getQueue();
                    Map<PathwayImpl,AnalysisResult> processedSet = cs.analyzedPaths;

                    inQueryQueue = queryQueue.size();
                    inPoolQueue = poolQueue.size();
                    completedTasks = (int) pool.getCompletedTaskCount();
                    inProccessedSet = processedSet.size();
                    duplicates = AnalysisAction.duplicates.get();
                    sanityCheck = (completedTasks == inProccessedSet + duplicates);
                }

                sb = new StringBuffer();
                sb.append("Checkpoint ").append(++counter).append(": ")
                    .append("QQ: ").append(inQueryQueue).append("\t")
                    .append("PQ: ").append(inPoolQueue).append("\t")
                    .append("CT: ").append(completedTasks).append("\t")
                    .append("AP: ").append(inProccessedSet).append("\t")
                    .append("DP: ").append(duplicates).append("\t")
                    .append("Sanity: ").append(sanityCheck);

                if(ps == null)
                    logger.info(sb.toString()  + nL);
                else
                    ps.println(sb.toString());
            }
        }
}
```

Here's what I see on the logs:

```
Sep 17, 2014 5:30:00 PM main.ConcurrencyService$QueryingAction run
INFO: Total number of queried paths: 81128
Sep 17, 2014 5:30:00 PM main.ConcurrencyService serve
INFO: All paths are queried and queued...
Initiating a timely shutdown of the pool..
...
Sep 17, 2014 5:49:49 PM main.ConcurrencyService serve
INFO: A total of 8620 tasks analyzed. Mean process time is: 1108.208 milliseconds.
...
Sep 17, 2014 5:49:54 PM main.ConcurrencyService$PeriodicLogAction outputLogInfo
INFO: Checkpoint 41: QQ: 0  PQ: 0   CT: 81128   AP: 8565    DP: 72508   Sanity: false
```

... which indicate:

1. The number of completed tasks is in agreement with the number of objects that were queried and queued. So nothing is missed..
2. The number of analyzed paths (thus results) and the number of duplicates do not add up to the number of completed tasks: 81128 - (8565 + 72508) = 55
3. The number of results accumulated does not match with reported process times from `AnalysisAction` class: 8565 vs 8620 (*i.e.* there are 55 results missing)

Not sure what could be the cause of this discrepancy, or where to begin debugging. I can't obviously step through 81128 tasks to investigate which 55 are missing, and why..

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** here are some clarifications addressing the question in the comments

- `DebugToolbox.submitProcTimes(long t)` is a synchronized static method, it simply adds t to an `ArrayList`.
- `isDone()` is a method in ConcurrencyService, I had accidentally removed it as I was trying to shorten the code I post here. I've edited the code to reflect how the method is implemented.

Comment: Whenever counting results over multiple threads you should default to using atomic counters - see the java.util.concurrent.atomic package for the provided atomic classes with as practical example [AtomicInteger][1] which should suit your needs. It's far too easy to have timing issues when using regular int for counters and lose results in the proces. Also be aware that you can still make mistakes while counting using atomic integers. I recommend incrementAndGet() when using it.


  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Comment: @3xil3 The number of duplicates is an `AtomicInteger`, as you can see in `AnalysisAction` class above. The other values are sizes of different collections, retrieved at a specific time point after all the execution is done.

Comment: My mistake - missed that. It is unclear to me if DebugToolbox.submitProcTime is multi-threading ready in terms of underlying structure(s) and synchronization. Can you highlight when cs.isDone() is actually set/calculated? I would have expected it to be set after the awaitTermination call in the finally block in your cs. This would lead me to believe that the pool is finishing up on the last tasks when the last logging statement is written in periodicLogAction. Also, can I correctly assume that the difference varies?

Comment: @3xil3 I have edited the question to address your questions. The last call of `periodicLogAction` is actually after the `finally` block, as you can see in the log excerpt. As for the number difference, it varies as you assumed correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check the map for presence of the key, then spend time generating the value, then put the value into the map.

While you're generating the value, another thread can process the same key. Since it's not been added yet, you now have two threads generating the same value. So the count of values generated is larger than  the final size of the map.

The solution is to add the result (may be a placeholder) and check for the key's presence atomically using `putIfAbsent()`.

Comment: If that was the case, wouldn't you expect the sum of results and duplicates to be **more** than the number of completed tasks, instead of less which is the case here?

Comment: Your idea of "duplicate" is when the key is already in the map. The  "duplicate" I am talking about is the case when the key is not in the map and there are two threads (or more) working on computing the value. Your counter counts the first duplicates, but not the second.

Comment: @Arkadiy nailed it.  Use the suggested putIfAbset method and check the return value.  When it comes back non-null you've found one of your missing duplicates.